# Software to create custom XML file

Tags: xml, user-interface, editor

I'm currently in the process of creating an android app that displays a biological key for species identification. At each step of the key, two or more images with text are displayed as buttons that describe some features, which on clicking,  take the user to the next corresponding node.  The key is defined in an XML file. A simplified snippet is shown below. I have created a large XML file, and it is becoming unwieldy. I was wondering if there was a tool in which I could graphically represent my XML file and the associations between nodes. Ideally, I would like to be able to edit, add, and delete nodes.

I know this is a big ask, but I am willing to create a tool to do this task. Just thought I better ask before I reinvent the wheel.

Cheers,

Neil

```
<uktrees>
<node id="root" >
    <terminal_node>false</terminal_node>
    <question>
        <text>Needle-like or scale-like Leaves that often overlap</text>
        <nextnode>conifers</nextnode>
        <image>pine.jpg</image>
    </question>  
    <question>
        <text>Leaves are not scales or needles and don't overlap </text>
        <nextnode>broad_leaf</nextnode>
        <image>broad_leaf.jpg</image>
    </question>
 </node>

 <node id="conifers">
      <terminal_node>true</terminal_node>
      <name>Conifers</name>
      <image>conifers.jpg</image>
      <description>A description of this species of group of species</description>
  </node>
      <node id="broad_leaf">
      <terminal_node>true</terminal_node>
      <name>Conifers</name>
      <image></image>
      <description>A description of this species of group of species</description>
  </node>
</uktrees>
```

Comment: You can check out OXygen XML editor oxygenxml.com/schema_diagram_img.html

Comment: Thanks for that, Tom. Oxygen looks promising, but I'm looking for a free tool as I don't intend to make any money from this app. I'll take a look at RDF.

Comment: Have you tried the default editor in Eclipse or the one provided with Android SDK plugin? There should be a Structure tab that allows you to add/remove nodes and view them as a simple tree. Editing attributes is also possible. That's not even close to what OXygen offers but it might suffice. Visual Studio has a decent editor as well, if you happen to have it.

Comment: As for RDF, I gave it some more thought and it seems like a terrible suggestion so I removed it from the original comment. It's great for this kind of tasks in general and it offers some neat capabilities BUT processing RDF/OWL is pretty expensive resource-wise. A no-go, when it comes to mobile development, cool thing in terms of Semantic Web and expert systems, though.

Comment: Thanks for the Eclipse tip. That helps a bit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I created my own tool using Qt, using the following as a guide: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/itemviews-simpledommodel.html